# I have button in my app, I want that whenever I will click on that dailer should be open how to that?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just want to open Android dailer when a button is pressed,
I found some code on stack overflow to do that. I did follow these steps:

I created a button and set onClick xml attribute in that button to call method openDailer().

Then, inside openDailer(), I pasted the code as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Now I run the app, whenever I am clicking on that button my app is stopped automatically.

Error like : Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped

Comment: Share your layout, activity code and your logcat... Your are doing fine... maybe, some Null pointer etc

Comment: Share your error log.

Comment: Please find the logs here logs link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-a25i3zfRNPX2pMdnBYV1Zvck0

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to achieve it.

1) Open the dialer using the intent, like you have done it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

The 'tel:' prefix is **mandatory**, otherwhise the following exception will be thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity.

***ACTION_DIAL requires no permissions.***

If you wish to make the call directly, just change the Intent to :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
```

Also, **add the the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Or 2) Have user to click on Phone_Number string and start the call (no persmissions or intents are required) with :

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

You need to add the following properties to your TextView

```
android:autoLink="phone" 
android:linksClickable="true"
```